# Deployment catalog uri from part

Tags: silverlight, mef

I have aggregate catalog and i'm loading deployment catalogs into it. Is it possible to find out later deployment catalog uri from part that i'm using.
Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really any way to do this.  At least, not any simple way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a list with the Uri and the DeploymentPackage as reference to this? That whay you can always look where a package came from.